# Facebook PHP-SDK login using JavaScript helper sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

During debugging we noticed the reason is sometimes the `fbsr_` cookie doesn't exist although we check for `status === 'connected'` before sending the request to the server.

JS:

```
FB.login(function (resp) {
    if (resp.status === 'connected') {
        // send request to server to login using the JavaScript helper
        // $.post('/fb/login', {}, function(){
        //     // display result etc.
        // });
    }
},  {scope: 'user_friends,email,user_birthday'});
```

PHP:

```
$fbApp = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'facebookappid',
    'app_secret' => 'facebooksecret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
$helper = $fbApp->getJavaScriptHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); // sometimes `fbsr_appid` cookie doesn't exist, so the access token is null
```

What is so confusing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't even when using the same browser same settings!

It's worth mentioning that we're still using the abandoned package `"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0"`, it was announced abandoned during our development so we decided to continue working with it for the current version.